# Glassfish Server Error when deploy .war: Error occurred during deployment: Exception while preparing the app : Invalid resource

Tags: java, deployment, web, glassfish, war

I am using the following:

- NetBeans IDE 7.3 (Build 201306052037)
- Java: 1.7.0_17; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 23.7-b01
- NetBeans integrated GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2 (build 5)

I created an RESTful Webservice with NetBeans, deployed it under NetBeans and it worked fine.

So I copied the generated .war file to another machine which uses:

- Oracle GlassFish Server 3.1.2.2
- java version "1.7.0_21" Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 23.21-b01, mixed mode)

When I want to deploy the .war file, I receive this error:

**remote failure: Error occurred during deployment: Exception while preparing the app : Invalid resource : webservice__pm. Please see server.log for more details.
Command deploy failed.**

Here my glassfish-resources.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE resources PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Resource Definitions//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-resources_1_5.dtd">
<resources>
    <jdbc-connection-pool allow-non-component-callers="false" associate-with-thread="false" connection-creation-retry-attempts="0" connection-creation-retry-interval-in-seconds="10" connection-leak-reclaim="false" connection-leak-timeout-in-seconds="0" connection-validation-method="auto-commit" datasource-classname="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource" fail-all-connections="false" idle-timeout-in-seconds="300" is-connection-validation-required="false" is-isolation-level-guaranteed="true" lazy-connection-association="false" lazy-connection-enlistment="false" match-connections="false" max-connection-usage-count="0" max-pool-size="32" max-wait-time-in-millis="60000" name="webservice" non-transactional-connections="false" pool-resize-quantity="2" res-type="javax.sql.DataSource" statement-timeout-in-seconds="-1" steady-pool-size="8" validate-atmost-once-period-in-seconds="0" wrap-jdbc-objects="false">
        <property name="portNumber" value="3306"/>
        <property name="databaseName" value="webservice"/>
        <property name="User" value="webservice"/>
        <property name="Password" value="webservice"/>
        <property name="URL" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/webservice?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"/>
        <property name="Url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/webservice?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"/>
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    </jdbc-connection-pool>
    <jdbc-resource enabled="true" jndi-name="webservice" object-type="user" pool-name="webservice"/>
</resources>
```

Here is my persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="DatensammlerPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>webservice</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Here is the error message from the **server.log**:

```
[#|2013-06-19T17:52:55.064+0200|SEVERE|oracle-glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.server|_ThreadID=68;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer prepare method|#]

[#|2013-06-19T17:52:55.064+0200|SEVERE|oracle-glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.server|_ThreadID=68;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Exception while preparing the app|#]

[#|2013-06-19T17:52:55.065+0200|SEVERE|oracle-glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.server|_ThreadID=68;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Invalid resource : webservice__pm
java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid resource : webservice__pm
        at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.lookupDataSourceInDAS(ConnectorRuntime.java:540)
        at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.lookupPMResource(ConnectorRuntime.java:469)
        at org.glassfish.persistence.common.PersistenceHelper.lookupPMResource(PersistenceHelper.java:63)
        at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.ProviderContainerContractInfoBase.lookupDataSource(ProviderContainerContractInfoBase.java:71)
        at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.<init>(PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:108)
        at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.loadPU(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:155)
        at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.<init>(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:120)
        at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$1.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:224)
        at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:495)
        at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.createEMFs(JPADeployer.java:233)
        at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.prepare(JPADeployer.java:168)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:871)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:410)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:461)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:212)
        at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException: Invalid resource : webservice__pm
        at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service.ConnectorResourceAdminServiceImpl$MyDataSource.validateResource(ConnectorResourceAdminServiceImpl.java:274)
        at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service.ConnectorResourceAdminServiceImpl$MyDataSource.setResourceInfo(ConnectorResourceAdminServiceImpl.java:255)
        at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service.ConnectorResourceAdminServiceImpl.lookupDataSourceInDAS(ConnectorResourceAdminServiceImpl.java:245)
        at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.lookupDataSourceInDAS(ConnectorRuntime.java:538)
        ... 40 more
|#]

[#|2013-06-19T17:52:55.070+0200|WARNING|oracle-glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.com.sun.enterprise.resource.deployer|_ThreadID=111;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|The log message is empty or null. Please log an issue against the component in the logger field.|#]

[#|2013-06-19T17:52:55.082+0200|WARNING|oracle-glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.com.sun.enterprise.resource.deployer|_ThreadID=111;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|The log message is empty or null. Please log an issue against the component in the logger field.|#]

[#|2013-06-19T17:52:55.083+0200|WARNING|oracle-glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.com.sun.enterprise.resource.deployer|_ThreadID=111;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|The log message is empty or null. Please log an issue against the component in the logger field.|#]

[#|2013-06-19T17:52:55.083+0200|SEVERE|oracle-glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.tools.admin.org.glassfish.deployment.admin|_ThreadID=68;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Exception while preparing the app : Invalid resource : webservice__pm
com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException: Invalid resource : webservice__pm
        at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service.ConnectorResourceAdminServiceImpl$MyDataSource.validateResource(ConnectorResourceAdminServiceImpl.java:274)
        at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service.ConnectorResourceAdminServiceImpl$MyDataSource.setResourceInfo(ConnectorResourceAdminServiceImpl.java:255)
        at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service.ConnectorResourceAdminServiceImpl.lookupDataSourceInDAS(ConnectorResourceAdminServiceImpl.java:245)
        at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.lookupDataSourceInDAS(ConnectorRuntime.java:538)
        at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.lookupPMResource(ConnectorRuntime.java:469)
        at org.glassfish.persistence.common.PersistenceHelper.lookupPMResource(PersistenceHelper.java:63)
        at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.ProviderContainerContractInfoBase.lookupDataSource(ProviderContainerContractInfoBase.java:71)
        at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.<init>(PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:108)
        at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.loadPU(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:155)
        at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.<init>(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:120)
        at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$1.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:224)
        at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:495)
        at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.createEMFs(JPADeployer.java:233)
        at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.prepare(JPADeployer.java:168)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:871)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:410)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:461)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:212)
        at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

I read a lot, that I should use **java:app/webservice** but it didn't work for me!!!
Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now I have the solution.
I forgot the JDBC Resource:
Open the Glassfish-Server Webinterface and navigate to Resources -> JDBC -> JDBC Resources and create a new one with the right Connection Pool. If the Resource and the Connection Pool are missing, the deployment will fail!!!
It worked for me without java:app/webservice...

Comment: Further for those having issues like this in Netbeans. By create a new one @elpronto means use make the JNDI name the same as your Data Source name in persistence.xml file.

Answer (score 5):

I had this same issue and it manifested in a great holabaloo of various strange exceptions that had absolutely nothing to do with my actual issue.

#### What's happened?

For some reason the resource for `jdbc/[your resource name]` has not been created in GlassFish and it throws you a `jdbc/[your resource name]__[generated thing, like "pm"]` as the source.

#### What to do?

One way (the one I used) to fix this is to manually go into your GlassFish admin console in the browser at `localhost:4848` and in the menu to the left go to `Resources` and follow the tree inside it: `JDBC > JDBC resources`. In the `JDBC Resources` tab you create a new resource and name it `jdbc/[your resource name]` the `__[generated thing, like "pm"]` is not necessary.

### BUT THAT DIDN'T WORK SO NOW WHAT DO I DO?!

This is exactly what happened to me and this is where I started getting the weird exceptions, like how it suddenly couldn't find my DB driver, even though I was staring at it in my dependencies folder.

#### How do I fix that then?

Restart NetBeans, refresh GlassFish and restart it if you have to. Run project and it should deploy.

*(I found the source of my problem from an exception about a MDB and when I removed it, it suddenly worked with my added resource, and then I could re-name it to whatever I wanted as long as there was a matching resource in GlassFish. You may need to have a lookover of your MDB JNDI settings in GlassFish as well and manually create a resource for them)*

#### Extra tip:

NetBeans will autocomplete existing resources when you're writing the `<jta-data-source>` tag. If it doesn't autocomplete, it probably doesn't exist.