# Configure Jndi names in Netbeans 8

Tags: jndi, netbeans-8

In `Netbeans 7.4` I used to create a `Persistence Unit` by choosing a JNDI name and then a database connection. In `Netbeans 8` I repeated the same process and started to give the old error

> Invalid resource : jdbc/something__pm

I also created a JDB resource with a new connection pool and the problem still remain. My way to solve this mistery was to delete line jdbc/something from persistence source. 
Is there any problem with this solution?

Comment: I didn't have that line but then my Data Source name under persistence.xml "Design View" was not matching the JDB resource name exactly once it was defined on the Glassfish server. For those needing to define the JNDI resource this was a good reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17196924/glassfish-server-error-when-deploy-war-error-occurred-during-deployment-excep